# TFS WorkItem Attachments can save but not load

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I can save an Attachment to a WorkItem like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServerUrl));
WorkItemStore tfsWorkItemStore = tfsTeamProjects.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
WorkItem tfsWorkItem = tfsWorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(tfsWorkItemId);

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\\Docs\testfile.txt");
Attachment tfsAttachment = new Attachment(fi.FullName);
tfsWorkItem.Attachments.Add(tfsAttachment);
tfsWorkItem.Save();
```

But when I try to get the list of Attachments for a WorkItem like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServerUrl));
WorkItemStore tfsWorkItemStore = tfsTeamProjects.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
WorkItem tfsWorkItem = tfsWorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(tfsWorkItemId);
foreach(Attachment tfsAttachment : tfsWorkItem.Attachments)
{
    // Do things here
}
```

`tfsWorkItem.Attachments` is always empty, even though I can see four attachments in the Objects tab on the TFS Web UI. And the WorkItem object that I am getting is the correct one.

Comment: Shouldn't be `in` instead of `:` in the `foreach` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember all details but [the code I wrote a while ago](https://github.com/giuliov/WitSync/blob/master/WitSyncEngine/WorkItems/Attachments.cs) use a wrapping class for enumeration that enables LINQ.

```
class AttachmentEnumerable : IEnumerable
{
    private AttachmentCollection underlyingCollection;

```
public AttachmentEnumerable(AttachmentCollection coll)
{ underlyingCollection = coll; }

public IEnumerator<Attachment> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (Attachment item in underlyingCollection)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

}
```

Also the `Attachment` object contains only a URL that you have to download later on.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried exactly the same scenario, and it does work for me. I am able to attach the file, and afterwards get it using the AttachmentCollection as you mentioned. What you could try to do is execute it in the same context like the following and verify if the AttachementCollection is still empty in this case:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsTeamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServerUrl));
WorkItemStore tfsWorkItemStore = tfsTeamProjects.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
WorkItem tfsWorkItem = tfsWorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(tfsWorkItemId);
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\\New Text Document.txt");
Attachment tfsAttachment = new Attachment(fi.FullName);
tfsWorkItem.Attachments.Add(tfsAttachment);
tfsWorkItem.Save();
foreach (Attachment tfsAttachment1 in tfsWorkItem.Attachments)
                {
                    // Do things here
                }
```

If the collection is not empty here, most probably there is another issue with the second call in which you are trying to get the attachments.

Comment: The same code that you have provided. First I have added the attachment  afterwards, I have been able to get it from another project. The third thing that I have tried is the combined approach, adding an attachment and right after getting it from the AttachmentCollection, in both cases I was able to get the attachments properly, so that why I have suggested the combined approach to you, to verify if the collection in this case is empty or not, and based on the results to see further where could lie the issue.

Comment: Read my question again, my two examples are separate. I don't want to add to a collection before iterating through it.

Comment: I have read it few times before answering it. You are saying that "tfsWorkItem.Attachments is always empty", while I am saying that it is not, regardless if I add files through the code that you have provided to that particular WorkItemId, or I am choosing a random WorkItemID that has attachments already. So based on that, I believe that you have some issue in the call, with either the ":" when trying to iterate through the collection, or with one of the variables being used there.

Comment: Colin Steel, I believe that you should re-read my answers again, and remove the down vote, that you have given me, cause I have provided you a information, what to do, and how to verify what is wrong in your case and also how to track if there something wrong with the approach taken!